# Unable to read in full table with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm new to webscraping and I'm trying to read in the full table at

https://www.fantasypros.com/daily-fantasy/mlb/draftkings-salary-changes.php.

However it only returns a table with 1486 values, cutting off before reaching any of the games that start after 4:10pm. Do I need to learn RSelenium to solve this?

```
fantasyHtml <- read_html("https://www.fantasypros.com/daily-fantasy/mlb/draftkings-salary-changes.php")
pitchersTable <- fantasyHtml %>% 
  html_table()

# this produces a table of only 1486 values, cutting off before any of the night games
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to extract more rows of the table with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.fantasypros.com/daily-fantasy/mlb/draftkings-salary-changes.php"
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

for(i in 1 : 500)
{
  print(i)
  command <- paste0("window.scrollBy(0,", i * 10, ")")
  remDr$executeScript(command)
}

fantasyHtml <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
pitchersTable <- fantasyHtml %>% html_table()
dim(pitchersTable[[1]])

[1] 2006    7
```

Comment: I am happy if it is useful ;)